# java.util.NoSuchElementException while building Neo4j on PPC

Tags: maven, neo4j

I am trying to build Neo4j on Linux on PPC platform, I am getting the following exception

```
[root@stgisv165 community]# ../../mavenbin/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/mvn clean install
Aug 28, 2013 6:16:45 p.m. com.google.inject.internal.MessageProcessor visit
INFO: An exception was caught and reported. Message: java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException   
    at java.util.AbstractList$1.next(libgcj.so.10)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forMember(InjectionPoint.java:116)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.<init>(InjectionPoint.java:73)
```

Here are the details of maven and os

```
[root@stgisv165 community]# ../../mavenbin/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin/mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-28 14:15:32+1200)
Maven home: /home/vekailai/Neo4j/mavenbin/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.5.0, vendor: Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-358.el6.ppc64", arch: "ppc64", family: "unix"
```

Any inputs will be really helpfull.

Thanks 
Venu

Answer (score 2):

From you errors, I think you might be encountering two issues.

- You seem to be using GCJ, and an old version of Java (1.5.0). I strongly recommend you use something like OpenJDK in its 1.7.x version (even 1.6.x has already been end-of-lifed).
- There are actually some incompatibilities between Maven 3.1.x and Maven 3.0.x that require some plugin upgrades. So, either you can ask for plugin upgrades in the upstream project, or use Maven 3.0.5.

Comment: Hello Baptiste Mathus, Thank you for the response, I used latest JDK and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad it helped. If so, think about plus'sing the answer ;-).